# One-line way to iterate over a list of classes and examine a single attribute

Tags: python

I'd like to iterate over a list of classes and see if a target string is found within a particular attribute of the class.  Here's how I can do it with a for loop:

```
# sample class
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

# make a quick list of classes
mylist = []
for i in "abcde":
    mylist.append(Test(i))

# see if any class "x" attribute contains "b" 
found = False
for i in mylist:
    if i.x == "b":
        found = True
```

This seems clumsy - there must be a better way.  I'm trying to do it with something that looks like:

```
if "b" in mylist.x:
```

Comment: If you have working code but want to find out how you could've written it better then you actually should be on Code Review not StackOverflow http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
any(i.x == 'b' for i in mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be easily achieved by using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) builtin function.

Sample code:

```
if "b" in map(lambda o: o.x, my_list):
    print "found"
```